# Links to useful resources to be kept and placed to FAQ

Tags: discussion, proposal, faq-proposed

I suggest we start collecting the links to the worthy resources that can help in developing the community and answering the questions.

The format I propose is: a **link** (URL) + a **sentence** about it

Let me start off with my list:

- http://poiskslov.com/
  finding a word by known letters
- [Этимологический словарь русского языка](http://ewiki.info/index.php/list/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- http://ewiki.info/index.php
  plenty of all sorts of dictionaries

Comment: Post your resources [here](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/71) in the appropriate section. :)

Answer (score 5):

- http://gramota.ru/ leading grammar reference website
- http://dic.academic.ru/ multi-dictionary search
- http://translit.cc/ translit converter

Answer (score 2):

- http://lingvo.ru multilingual dictionary
- http://rosental.virtbox.ru/ Rosenthal reference on spelling and style
- http://gramota.ru/spravka A place where profis answer tough questions (should be distinguished from just http://gramota.ru offering word search
- http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/online/ A list of online dictionaries
- Телефонная справочная Института Виноградова: http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=sprav, +7 495 695-26-48

Answer (score 2):

[Russian National Corpus](http://www.ruscorpora.ru) is very useful for all kinds of collocation searches and not only for that. Plus it contains texts from different centuries, both fiction and non-fiction, AND it has a part with speech records.

A resource that is useful for learning Russian pronunciation is [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/languages/ru/)

Answer (score 1):

**Public domain libraries:**

- [Фундаментальная электронная библиотека «Русская литература и фольклор» (ФЭБ)](http://feb-web.ru/)
- [Русская виртуальная библиотека](http://www.rvb.ru/)
- [«Собрание классики» Библиотеки Мошкова](http://az.lib.ru/)
- [Российская государственная библиотека](http://elibrary.rsl.ru/)
- [Российская национальная библиотека](http://leb.nlr.ru/)
- [Некоммерческая электронная библиотека «ImWerden»](http://imwerden.de/)

Answer (score 1):

The site [ru.wiktionary.org](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) provides conjugation tables for verbs.