# List of commonly cited references on RLU.SE

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

I suggest starting a list of commonly cited references here. For FAQ. So that people can look up what *Dahl*, *Gramota*, *Lopatin*, or *Ozhegov* refer to. It would be different from [Links to useful resources to be kept and placed to FAQ](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/links-to-useful-resources-to-be-kept-and-placed-to-faq) in that it would list references used here, not the recommended references for Russian language in general. It could be considered as an author-style bibliography for this site.

Comment: Guys, should this thing be here or in the main namespace? I'd like to have it started already. Since we're asking people to search for info before posting a question, it's reasonable to provide a list of places where to search.

Comment: OK, I think I understand: since it's about the references, cited on this site, so about the site, it should be in meta. Since it's not a question about the Russian language, it should also be in meta. So, it'll be in meta. I'll start it here.

Answer (score 2):

- [Dahl] Даль, Владимир Иванович. [Толковый словарь живого великорусского языка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0). Online: http://dal.sci-lib.com/, http://www.slova.ru/, [Yandex](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/), http://sldal.ru/
- [Gramota] Справочно-информационный портал [Gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru). Sections: word spell-checker (main page) and user questions service (http://gramota.ru/spravka/)
- [Efremova] Ефремова, Татьяна Фёдоровна. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный. [Online](http://efremova.info)
- [Lopatin] Лопатин, Владимир Владимирович. Орфографический словарь. Online: http://www.dict.t-mm.ru/lopatin/, http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=2684
- [Ozhegov] Ожегов, Сергей Иванович. [Толковый словарь русского языка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%9E%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0). Online: http://ozhegov.info, http://slovarozhegova.ru/, http://www.ozhegov.org/, http://ozhegov-online.ru/
- [Rosenthal] Розенталь, Дитмар Эльяшевич.

  - Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию. Online: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm, http://lib.rus.ec/b/342635
  - Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. Online: http://rosental.virtbox.ru/
  - Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати. Online: http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/rozent1
- [Vasmer] Фасмер, Макс. [Этимологический словарь русского языка](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9C._%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). [Online](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho).

Comment: Can someone help with the link to Gramota please? For some reason, it is displayed incorrectly and I cannot spot the error.

Comment: I believe the problem is that there are three `[..]` blocks in a row in the source. Try to separate them somehow. I can't try myself now, I don't see the `edit` links on posts here.

Comment: @LevLevitsky You're right, corrected, thanks!

Comment: Many people also use [Vasmer's dictionary for etimology](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/query.cgi?basename=\usr\local\share\starling\morpho\vasmer\vasmer&root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&encoding=utf-eng)

Comment: @Olga: Thanks, added.