# How long we are planning to stay in beta?

Tags: discussion

What can I do to help promote this site from *beta* up to *release*?
Are there any conditions that must be satisfied?

The last of the [Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) was asked more that 3 years ago: [How to promote our site?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/how-to-promote-our-site)
What's next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general reference for this topic is [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614).

With 2 questions per day, this site is firmly in the "in-between" group:

> Is your site in between these two categories? You don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site might be, you have a home here in the SE network.

The site would need to attract a much larger audience to reach the 10 questions/day threshold. On the other hand, it does not *need* to do this; it can stay in the present form indefinitely, with the word "beta" increasingly perceived as a misnomer by SE.